# VSCode: Open file in project

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Mac OS X with Visual Studio Code 0.10.10.

How do I use the keyboard to open a file, using its partial name, in the currently open project? I can't find a command in the Command Palette that would enable me to do this. There is a command that does this for Working Files (see screenshot), but *not* for the currently open project.

[image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`>` prefix is for running commands in VSCode.

To open a file in the current project press <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type the full / partial name of the wanted file. VSCode uses fuzzy search, so you can even get away with typos in your input.

Comment: `cmd+p` on mac and `ctrl+p` on windows

Comment: ...or if you are really lazy you can open the command palette using `F1`.

Answer (score 9):

There is not a proper command for this but if your file has any file extension you can just open the command palette and replace the `>` with a `.`

It will have a section of the open files at the top and "file and symbol results" at the bottom containing every file name containing a `.` (= all files with a file extension)

If you know the name of the file you can simply remove the `>` in the command palette and type the name and it will show the file and symbols results again for any file containing what you have typed.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To open known file on a current project if you aware the file name is Ctrl+P Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Open file opening pallet with ctrl+p (on Windows) and cmd+p on Mac OSX.

[image]

In that pallet you can either type the `file name` or a `file relative path` like shown in the below image

[image]

The important point for relative path is that, it should not start with a dot `.` but should start with a fwd slash `/`

Absolute path can be used as well.

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl+O opens the command palette right to the file search mode. The command in the shortcuts is "workbench.action.files.openLocalFile".