# Open/search file in VScode

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

VScode version: 1.13
OS version: macOS sierra 10.12.5

I am wondering if VScode could open/search a file by entering the Path with auto-complete like vim or Emacs?

Answer (score 0):

Opening a file in your project : see [VSCode: Open file in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944316/vscode-open-file-in-project).  if you already have the find panel open with a search term the finds will be highlighted in the next opened file.

I like the CtrL-P then type a . to get your files by extension and then choose the one you want to open.  Your preexisting search terms will be highlighted.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that is not exactly what I am looking for. `CtrL-P`(`⌘-P` on mac) can only search in the opened files, I am wondering if VScode could open one file(whether it has been reached) like ":e" in vim.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to search for a search term across all files in your project?  If so, VSCode can do that.  Using the magnifying glass/ search icon in the actions panel, you can search across all files, it will show results across all files and you can click on those to go directly to that location whether it was previously opened or not.  Or do you just what to open files in your project from CtrL-P?  VSCode can do that to.  Tell us exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  I don't know what ".e" does in vim.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `Ctrl + P`, then start typing?

The filename is fuzzy matched. Press ENTER to open.

[image]